# SymPy: Taylor series using variable other than x?

Tags: python, sympy

I've been searching the docs, but I'm stuck: SymPy seems to be assuming a variable "x" even when I've only declared "t" and "y(t)".  I asked it to give me a series for y(t), and this is what I get...

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> var('t')
t
>>> y = Function("y")
>>> s = y(t).series(t, 0, 4)
>>> pprint(s)
                             ⎛  2      ⎞│         ⎛  3      ⎞│           
                           2 ⎜ d       ⎟│       3 ⎜ d       ⎟│           
                          t ⋅⎜───(y(x))⎟│      t ⋅⎜───(y(x))⎟│           
                             ⎜  2      ⎟│         ⎜  3      ⎟│           
         ⎛d       ⎞│         ⎝dx       ⎠│x=0      ⎝dx       ⎠│x=0    ⎛ 4⎞
y(0) + t⋅⎜──(y(x))⎟│    + ────────────────── + ────────────────── + O⎝t ⎠
         ⎝dx      ⎠│x=0           2                    6
```

How do I get a Taylor series with d/dt's instead of d/dx's, and y(t) instead of y(x)?

*(btw, trying to substitute t for x doesn't work because x isn't even defined so you get an error)*

**EDIT:** For clarification, this is what I want:

```
>>> pprint(s)
                             ⎛  2      ⎞│         ⎛  3      ⎞│           
                           2 ⎜ d       ⎟│       3 ⎜ d       ⎟│           
                          t ⋅⎜───(y(t))⎟│      t ⋅⎜───(y(t))⎟│           
                             ⎜  2      ⎟│         ⎜  3      ⎟│           
         ⎛d       ⎞│         ⎝dt       ⎠│t=0      ⎝dt       ⎠│t=0    ⎛ 4⎞
y(0) + t⋅⎜──(y(t))⎟│    + ────────────────── + ────────────────── + O⎝t ⎠
         ⎝dt      ⎠│t=0           2                    6
```

or even

```
>>> pprint(s)
                             ⎛  2      ⎞│         ⎛  3      ⎞│           
                           2 ⎜ d       ⎟│       3 ⎜ d       ⎟│           
                          h ⋅⎜───(y(t))⎟│      h ⋅⎜───(y(t))⎟│           
                             ⎜  2      ⎟│         ⎜  3      ⎟│           
         ⎛d       ⎞│         ⎝dt       ⎠│t=0      ⎝dt       ⎠│t=0    ⎛ 4⎞
y(0) + h⋅⎜──(y(t))⎟│    + ────────────────── + ────────────────── + O⎝h ⎠
         ⎝dt      ⎠│t=0           2                    6
```

Comment: Looks normal to me. The `t` and the `x` are semantically distinct, and they really *shouldn't* be treated as the same variable.

Comment: there is no `x` defined anywhere.  it is magically appearing in the output, unbidden.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess that it doesn't want *t* passed as an arg

sympy generally works with symbolic expressions, a slightly different perspective than a function

```
y = Function("y")
y.series(t, 0, 4)
Out[7]: t
```

or with a little something to actually give series terms:

```
y = sin(t)

y.series(t, 0, 8)
Out[10]: t - t**3/6 + t**5/120 - t**7/5040 + O(t**8)
```